# Misspelling cleanup -- every time you make a typo, the errorists win

Tags: discussion, status-completed, cleanup

Here's a cleanup project to help improve the information on the site.  Occasionally words are intentionally misspelled, and that is OK.  We are only interested in correcting mistakes.

Fix words that are used often on this site and sometimes spelled wrong:

- <s>[pag](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=pag) - page</s>
- <s>[doman](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=doman) - domain</s>
- <s>[domian](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=domian) - domain</s>
- <s>[analitic](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=analitic) - analytics</s>
- <s>[anylitic](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=anylitic) - analytics</s>
- <s>[hsot](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=hsot) - host</s>
- <s>[acces](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=acces) - access</s>
- <s>[acess](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=acess) - access</s>
- <s>[apace](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=apace) - Apache</s>
- <s>[appache](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=appache) - Apache</s>
- <s>[gogle](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=gogle) - Google</s>
- <s>[googel](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=googel) - Google</s>
- <s>[goog](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=goog) - good or Google</s>
- <s>[pagrank](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=pagrank) - Pagerank</s>
- <s>[wordpres](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=wordpres) - WordPress</s>
- <s>[serch](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=serch) - search</s>
- <s>[searh](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=searh) - search</s>
- <s>[adsene](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=adsene) - AdSense</s>
- <s>[desing](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=desing) - design</s>
- <s>[desig](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=desig) - design</s>
- <s>[contant](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=contant) - content</s>
- <s>[sitmap](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=sitmap) - sitemap</s>
- <s>[sugest](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=sugest) - suggest</s>
- <s>[bandwith](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=bandwith) - bandwidth</s>
- <s>[pengiun](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=pengiun) - penguin</s>

Fix words that are often spelled wrong:

- <s>[teh](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=teh) - the</s>
- <s>[loose](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=loose) - lose (usually)</s>
- <s>[adn](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=adn) - and</s>
- <s>[necesary](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=necesary) - necessary</s>
- <s>[wich](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=wich) - which</s>
- <s>[shoud](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=shoud) - should</s>
- <s>[im](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=im) - I'm (usually)</s>
- <s>[ive](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=ive) - I've</s>
- <s>[weve](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=weve) - we've</s>

As with all clean-up projects, don't just fix this one issue. More than likely there are other issues with the post that should be addressed.  Edits should be rejected in the edit queue unless they attempt to fix **all** the major problems in a given post.  That may include:

- Non-descriptive titles
- Capitalization
- Formatting

  - Paragraph breaks
  - Lists
  - Code blocks
- Other misspellings
- Grammar
- Tags (either inappropriate or missing)
- Remove "hi", "thanks", "please help", "here is my question", and signatures

Be aware of front-page flooding. **Only fix a few posts at a time**.  It usually takes a while to edit each post properly, so you won't want to do to many of them at once anyway.

It is also common that posts that have spelling errors should be closed.  If the post is:

- unclear
- duplicate
- a site review or other problem that no other webmaster will encounter
- asks for third party tools (or other off-site resources)

flag the post to be closed.

Please feel free to suggest new spelling errors or edit this post to indicate that an item has been completely taken care of.

Comment: Good job as usual. I'm going to do a clean and freshen up before Christmas myself. Please note what Stephen pointed out, if your going on clean-up missions try to do it in small amounts to keep those who use notifications happy, as from personal experience people get annoyed with flooding of the frontpage with old threads. Also as Steve also mentioned improve the questions and answers more than just the spelling if you can.

Comment: For reference, [here is where we called out bybe for excessive editing](http://meta.webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/943/enough-with-the-bold-italic-and-editing-every-old-question-please), luckily we didn't scare him away and he is now an excellent moderator.

Comment: Perhaps add 'notifactions' as per bybe's message. Heh.

Comment: I corrected bybe's comment.  Luckily, I don't see that mis-spelling used elsewhere.

Comment: @bybe since it's important for the people editing to have correct spelling/grammar, I'll point out you should have put "you're" instead of "your" in your comment :)

Comment: My spelling / grammar is awful ;)

Answer (score 1):

I'm very happy this appears to be well received by the community here.  Kudos to those that have helped out with this effort.  The following folks deserve a round of applause for their editing efforts:

- [ChrisF](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/users/288/chrisf)
- [Grant Palin](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/users/132/grant-palin)
- [John Conde](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1253/john-conde)
- [dan](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/users/28389/dan)

who have all done some editing and then marked an item as completed.

(Feel free to edit this post and add the names of others who have helped.)

Comment: Just noting that Grant has been doing a really impressive job with editing, as Stephen and the others have as well - good work!

Comment: I was just glad to get through all the "lose" spelled "loose" cases.  I'm not sure why, but that is one misspelling that really grinds my gears.  I usually don't even notice "its" vs "it's" but I  can't read: "you just can't loose" without flinching. Probably because the pronunciation is different.

Comment: That was a daunting list if I remember correctly - glad you didn't _lose_ your patience ;-)

Comment: Maybe we should add abbreviations to the list, such as: GA, GWT, FB, etc...? Questions that use only abbreviations won't be indexed by Google for those keywords, or found in search results here, and users may not understand them either.

Comment: Lets save that for a separate cleanup effort.  I'm getting antsy to finish this one up.  I was thinking another misspelling cleanup in the spring would be good.  We could have an abbreviation cleanup sometime in the meantime.

Comment: Sounds good to me.